# Session php statement

Tags: php, session

how can i command this into a statement that will just put all the $_POST[] into a session without have to write each line out.

```
<?php session_start(); 
$_SESSION['s_type'] = $_POST['s_type'];
$_SESSION['s_uname'] = $_POST['s_uname'];
$_SESSION['s_email'] = $_POST['s_email'];
$_SESSION['s_promo'] = $_POST['s_promo'];
$_SESSION['s_ctry'] = $_POST['s_ctry'];
?>
```

Comment: A direct assignment can overwrite any variable in your `$_SESSION` user passing in post data. this is very dangerous. isn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['POST'] = $_POST;
echo $_SESSION['POST']['s_type'];
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't like the nesting of Marc B,

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v){
    $_SESSION[$k] = $v;
}
```

Comment: Errr...now that I think about it, don't do this unless you add some input validation. What if someone were to $_POST['user_id']? Do what Marc B said!

Comment: This is better and more elegant I guess... And not to worry about $_POST['user_id']. We can do something like $_SESSION["POST $k"] = $v;

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reason to be selective about which `$_POST` values go to session storage and which don't (for example, if you had a CAPTCHA that had to be re-entered each time, or a credit card number or something sensitive), make an array of the `$_POST` keys to store and iterate over it:

```
// We won't store s_email in $_SESSION. All others stored
$store_to_session = array('s_stype','s_uname','s_promo','s_city');
foreach ($store_to_session as $s) {
  $_SESSION[$s] = $_POST[$s];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION = $_POST;
```

Would create a copy of the $_POST array and assign it to $_SESSION, which accomplishes what you are asking.  But this will also wipe out any array members in the $_SESSION array.  So I recommend a loop, which will maintain the array members already in $_SESSION.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=> $val){
    $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

Instead of direct assigning `$_POST` into `$_SESSION` create a nested score like this:

```
$_SESSION['putScopeNameHere'] = $_POST;
```

In this case, your `session` data is also available for you after `post` data assignment.